# Does Cloudfront Disable/Enable effectively "invalidate" all files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I know it takes longer and more resources, but does doing a full disable/enable in Cloudfront invalidate all the files?   Sometimes it seems safer to just do everything than rely on the developers sending us an exactly list of files. (We have a static HTML site with javascript code hosted in S3 and exposed via Cloudfront.)

I tried the disable/enable yesterday, but today, people were saying it looks their code changes were not being used on the website.

Great feature in the future would be to invalidate all files changed since the last validation.  That should be easy for them to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I invalidate, I use the '/*' specifier, and it invalidates everything. Works every time for us.

There would be some nominal increase in processing time and cost, but I don't believe it is significant.

Comment: Good, I didn't know that /* would handle the the subdirectories, but of course subdirectories are kind of an abstraction that doesn't really exist in S3.  So that's a better technique, but since I did the disable/enable, I'm curious if that would basically act the same?

Comment: Yes It matches all keys rather than all subdirectories. I am not sure of the disable/enable behavior.